# How to show MDI Child in 2nd monitor screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

my question is that there are any ways to drag / show mdi child form in the another monitors. i want to drag child form and show it in another monitors.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of MDI is that MDI children are contained within the parent.
If you want to show one form on screen A and another form on screen B, then you need to stay away from mdi app.
So the answer to your question is no, can not be done.